# Git: How to recover a file after a pull / failed auto merge?

Tags: git

I was about to get the latest with a `git pull origin master` and realized I have conflicts in some config files. But I also have other files to checkin, which I dont want to loose.

Since these conflicts are local config files, I simply deleted them, hoping to retrieve them again by doing a new pull request.

Now trying to do another `git pull origin master` and it says

> "Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files. please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm ' as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'."

So how can I recover these deleted config files with the latest state from the repository? (I didn't care about my local changes to these files, hence I deleted it)

Shall I now do for each config file:

`git checkout -- path/to/individual_file`

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you have some files to commit you could stash them with `git stash`, then reset back to the `HEAD` with `git reset --hard HEAD`, pull the changes with `git pull` fix all the conflicts and then apply your stash on the new HEAD with `git stash apply`

You can also create a temporary `branch` if you prefer to store your local changes, to the reset and pull on the master and the recover your local changes from the temporary branch.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `$ git reset --hard HEAD` to return the `HEAD` state.

Then do `git pull` again, fix the conflicts, then commit your fix.

Comment: thanks. If i do `git reset --hard HEAD` I wouldn't loose my other local changes?

Comment: That will remove all uncommitted changes, yes.